# How do i construct a WideString with a diacratic in a non-unicode Delphi version?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-5, unicode-string, widestring

i am trying to construct a (test) `WideString` of:

> á ([U+00E1  Small Letter Latin A with acute](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm))

but using it's decomposed form:

> LATIN SMALL LETTER A ([U+0061](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm)) COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT ([U+0301](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm))

So i have the code fragment:

```
var
    test: WideString;
begin
   test := #$0061#$0301;
   MessageBoxW(0, PWideChar(test), 'Character with diacratic', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
end;
```

Except it doesn't appear to work:

[image]

This *could* be a bug in [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but i'm going to go ahead and say that it's more likely the bug is in *my* code.

Some other variations i have tried:

```
test := WideString(#$0061#$0301);


const
    SmallLetterLatinAWithAcuteDecomposed: WideString = #$0061#$0301;
test := SmallLetterLatinAWithAcuteDecomposed


test := #$0061+#$0301;  (Doesn't compile; incompatible types)


test := WideString(#$0061)+WideString(#$0301);  (Doesn't compile; crashes compiler)


test := 'a'+WideString(#$0301);  (Doesn't compile; crashes compiler)


//Arnauld's thought:
test := #$0301#$0061;
```

### Bonus chatter

- [Handling a Unicode String in Delphi Versions <= 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383195/handling-a-unicode-string-in-delphi-versions-2007)

Comment: What Delphi version are you using? I seem to recall that some versions are more sensitive to the compilation environment's locale settings than others are.

Comment: i am, indeed, still using Delphi 5. Updated tags.

Comment: Works OK with D2007 (tested the first snippet)..

Comment: @Ian Good for you trying to scrag some live out of the old dog that is D5. But for bonus points you really should be doing this in D2!!  ;-)

Comment: Let's have some love for Delphi 1.  16 bits ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: @Warren The love ran out when 64 bit systems arrived

Comment: @David Heffernan: Our company was using D1 back when you had to sign an NDA to get the VCL source code!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Best answer:**

```
const
    n: WideString = '';  //n=Nothing

s := n+#$0061+#$0301;
```

This fixes all cases i have below that otherwise fail.

---

The only variant that works is to declare it as a constant:

```
AccentAcute: WideString = #$0301;
AccentAcute: WideString = WideChar($0301);
AccentAcute: WideString = WideChar(#$0301);
AccentAcute: WideString = WideString(#$0301);
```

Sample Usage:

```
s := 'Pasta'+AccentAcute;
```

### *Constant* based syntaxes that **do not work**

- `AccentAcute: WideString = $0301;`
              *incompatible types*
- `AccentAcute: WideString = #0301;`
  *gives [image]*
- `AccentAcute: WideString = WideString($0301);`
  *invalid typecast*
- `AccentAcute: WideString = WideString(#$0301);`
  *invalid typecast*
- `AccentAcute: WideChar = WideChar(#0301);`
   *gives `Pastai`*
- `AccentAcute: WideChar = WideChar($0301);`
   *gives `Pasta´`*

### **Other syntaxes that fail**

- `'Pasta'+WideChar($0301)`
  *gives `Pasta´`*
- `'Pasta'+#$0301`
  *gives `Pasta´`*
- `WideString('Pasta')+#$0301`
  *gives [image]*

---

Summary of all *constant* based syntaxes i found think up:

```
AccentAcute: WideString =            #$0301;   //works
AccentAcute: WideString =   WideChar(#$0301);  //works
AccentAcute: WideString = WideString(#$0301);  //works
AccentAcute: WideString =             $0301;   //incompatble types
AccentAcute: WideString =    WideChar($0301);  //works
AccentAcute: WideString =  WideString($0301);  //invalid typecast

AccentAcute: WideChar =            #$0301;     //fails, gives Pasta´
AccentAcute: WideChar =   WideChar(#$0301);    //fails, gives Pasta´
AccentAcute: WideChar = WideString(#$0301);    //incompatible types
AccentAcute: WideChar =             $0301;     //incompatible types
AccentAcute: WideChar =    WideChar($0301);    //fails, gives Pasta´
AccentAcute: WideChar =  WideString($0301);    //invalid typecast
```

### Rearranging `WideChar` can work, as long as you only append to a variable

```
//Works
t := '0123401234012340123';
t := t+WideChar(#$D840);
t := t+WideChar(#$DC00);

//fails
t := '0123401234012340123'+WideChar(#$D840);
t := t+WideChar(#$DC00);

//fails
t := '0123401234012340123'+WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);

//works
t := '0123401234012340123';
t := t+WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);

//works
t := '';
t := t+WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);

//fails; gives junk
t := ''+WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);

//crashes compiler
t := WideString('')+WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);

//doesn't compile
t := WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);
```

Definitely hitting against compiler nonsense; cases that weren't tested tested fully. Yes, i know David, we should upgrade.

Comment: Essentially; Delphi 5 not a good fit for Unicode development. :-)

Comment: Hopefully this nonsense is just limited to the compiler's ability to read my source code files. This should all be fixed once i've set my generation of unit-test data of characters outside the *Basic Multilingual Plane* (BMP) and tests of *surrogate pairs*.

Comment: ... Then Delphi 5 was still way out of date!

Comment: David Heffernan's got you covered there.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Delphi 5/7:

```
var
  test: WideString;
begin

   test := WideChar($0061);
   test := test + WideChar($0301);

   MessageBoxW(0, PWideChar(test), 'Character with diacratic', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
end;
```

In short:

- In delphi 5 and delphi 7, it does not appear that concatenating WideChars to WideString works using `#$xxxx` form literals.
- `#` doesn't seem to work as you'd expect for unicode literals.
- You can't just add two or more  widechars in a single expression, like this:

  ```
  test := WideChar(a)+WideChar(b);  // won't compile in D5/D7.
  ```

Comment: The `'string' + WideChar($xxxx)` syntax fails for `'Pasta'+WideChar($0301);`. It generates `Pasta´`, rather than `Pastá`.

Comment: Ian you can't use `'ansistring'` literals and just append WideChars to them!  It seems crazy to me that you would even try that in Delphi 5.

Comment: Why would you think `'string'` is an `AnsiString`? The compiler can treat it as a `WideString` during compilation.

Comment: You *can* add more than one `WideChar` in a single expression, as long as you're appending to an existing string: `t := t+WideChar(#$D840)+WideChar(#$DC00);` or `t := t+WideChar($D840)+WideChar($DC00);`

Comment: Building off our thoughts of splitting up otherwise equivalent concatenations, led me to find more cases that work, and some that don't. In the end i found the best fix was always to concatenate with a variable or constant.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try #$0301#$0061 (i.e. diacritic first)?

OK.

So #$.... only handles ASCII 8 bits constants in this version.

You can just use a workaround using memory level:

```
type
    TWordArray  = array[1..MaxInt div SizeOf(word)-2] of word;
    // start at [1], just as WideStrings
    // or: TWordArray  = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(word)-1] of word;
    PWordArray = ^TWordArray;

var
  test: WideString;
begin
  test := '12'; // or SetLength(test,2);
  PWordArray(test)[1] := $61; 
  PWordArray(test)[2] := $301;
  MessageBoxW(0, pointer(test), 'Character with diacratic', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
end;
```

This will always work since you don't play with chars/widechars and such.

And it will also work as expected with Unicode version of Delphi.

Comment: i tried it; updated question. i would expect it to not work since there is no "previous" character for the diacritic to apply to.

Comment: The problem is `#` only works for ascii codepoints (61 is fine, but $301 is > than $FF, so no go) in delphi 5.

Comment: You are allowed to use `#$xxxx` syntax in Delphi; it works for me (see above), it works in VirtualTreeview (VirtualTrees.pas), and it works in Jedi (`JclUnicode.pas`). The bugs i'm hitting seem to revolve around the compiler's interpretation of them in various forms. But at a basic level the syntax `ThreeEighths: WideString =  #$215C;` is accepted.

Comment: @Ian To circumvent the #$.... inconsistency between Delphi versions, using direct in-memory access with words is safe and fast. The `PWordArray(test)[]` access is safe and fast.