# Using New/Dispose with record pointer containing WideString

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7

I have very old code (from D3):

```
TMyRecord  = record
  Index   : Integer;
  Header  : String[70];
  Strings : Array[1..MAX_VALUES] of String[70];
end;

TMyClass = class(TComponent)
  FData  : ^TMyRecord;
  ...
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  New(FData);     
  ...
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
   Dispose(FData);
   inherited;
end;
```

Q: Is it safe to replace `String[70]` with `WideString;` and `Array[1..MAX_VALUES] of String[70]` with `Array[1..MAX_VALUES] of WideString`? (Please explain why)

I need this to support Unicode in Delphi 7.

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: `Dispose` calls `_Finalize` routine that correctly frees all internal structures. How are you going to use this type?

Comment: Simple answer is yes. This is a managed type, and `New` and `Dispose` initialise and finalise managed types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general you should never use Widestring. 
It is only meant for compatibility with COM BSTR.

However you are using a pre-2009 version so if you **need** Unicode you don't have a choice.
WideString is dynamically allocated, when you `new` the record Delphi will add code to initialize your strings.
You don't have to initialize them yourself.

Just like shortstrings WideStrings are not reference counted, but they will be destroyed when you `dispose` the record.
If you assign the Widestring to another Widestring Delphi will make a copy, this is slightly less efficient than refcounting, but otherwise not a problem.

Whenever a Widestring goes out of scope it is destroyed.

Be careful with PWideChar, these will be dangling when a WideString is destroyed.

**VCL cannot display WideString**
Note that whilst Delphi 7 **does** have support for Unicode with Widestring the VCL cannot display your Widestrings, it can only display AnsiString.
If you want to display WideStrings use the TNT components, see this answer for more info: [Handling a Unicode String in Delphi Versions <= 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383195/handling-a-unicode-string-in-delphi-versions-2007)

If you are going to assign WideString to (Ansi)string you might as well use plain string, because you'll lose all your unicode.
You can use UTF8, but D7 cannot display UTF8 either.

**Caveat: indexing in Asian locales**
A further caveat is that `MyWidestring[i]` does not necessarily mean the ith character because Unicode cannot be fully expressed in 2 bytes per char.
Unless you're using an asian language this should not affect you.

> Q: Is it safe to replace String[70] with WideString;

Yes, but it is easier to replace `String[70]` with `String` (aka AnsiString).  Because the D7 VCL supports AnsiString but not WideString.
Other than that you don't really have a problem.

**Further reading**
https://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/Delphi+String+Types

Comment: Thanks. what do you mean by *"Be careful with PWideChar"*? should I be worry if I use for e.g. `Windows.ExtTextOutW(Handle, X, Y, TextFlags, nil, PWideChar(WideText)...`?

Comment: No that's fine. Only if you perpetuate P(Wide)Chars after the string they point to has already gone out of scope will you have a problem.